# SQL Server 2008 select date only from field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with dates & times in columns.

I need to select the date portion only from a column named `last_date`.

I see all the information on selecting, but they do not include a column name.

Could someone point out how to select the date portion from a field in a table using the column name??

Thank you

Comment: Provide us more information: table structure, data sample, what you've tested,...

Comment: To select just the date part try `CONVERT(DATE, last_date,101)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST( last_date as DATE) from TableA
```